What is the density of solid methane at atmospheric pressure?
I'm curious about the density of solid methane since it might be slightly more energy dense than liquid natural gas. The materials project computes the density to be 0.433 g/cm3 which is higher than liquid methane's 0.422 g/cm3.
But I can't seem to find experimental data anywhere after looking on Wikipedia, NIST, and Google Scholar. These are the only papers I can find:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/6/17/001/pdf
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article-abstract/37/3/288/47163/Structure-and-compression-of-crystalline-methane

I assume the little gain in energy density is counterbalanced by eventual manipulation issues and extra energy expense for cooling, freezing, keeping,  melting, warming up.

Agreed. Some of that density improvement will be lost on the 20C of cooling needed to go from liquid to solid. Also, industry already knows how to transport and handle liquid methane. But I'm still annoyed that nobody has an experimental number for this!

My trusty CRC Handbook gives 0.466 at -164 (Bp.). Probably a typo.

Interesting, do they have a source? It's so weird that nobody measured this directly. 10% improvement on LNG is interesting, but probably not enough to be worth it.
